# NextJS Amplify Rewrite Incorrect User Agent Header

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

After deploying a Next.js app on AWS Amplify and using a rewrite to an external server, when inspecting the request headers, the User Agent header is `Amazon CloudFront` instead of the user's user agent.

When deploying the same Next.js app on Vercel, the user agent reflects the actual user's user agent, which is the expected behaviour.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue on AWS Amplify?